# AssertionError in TestCafe: expected &#39; &#39; to deeply equal &#39; &#39;

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm writing test in TestCafe and I should check, that the field for typing is empty. I'm doing it using *eql assertion*

```
.expect(instanceQuery.resultField.value).eql('')
```

But I'm getting an error: *AssertionError: expected ' ' to deeply equal ' '*

Answer (score 3):

When I copy/paste your error message in a console, I get empty space characters, and the eql assertion expects an empty string.

Sometimes it happens that when you copy stuff to/from the console you get different space characters. Make sure you type yourself the empty string.

You can try it out here: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-germain-y9qxq)